# python Long to Byte Array of 2 byte using struct

Tags: python, python-2.7, arrays

I am converting long or int to bytearray in python using struct

ba = struct.pack('H',12)

output : '\x0c\x00'
length 2 bytes

but if i convert 
ba = struct.pack('H',12345)

output : '90'
i need to encode to hex for desired out put
ba.encode('hex')
in this case output is 
output : 3930
and length is 4

why this is happening, it should give 2 byte result without encoding ?

**my usecase is i need to convert long to bytearray of desired bytearray size.**

Comment: I don't really get what your achievement is. Do you want to obtain `b"0c00"` with the input `12`?

Comment: actually i wanted to create a generic function with input as long and output as 2 byte byte array, using struct if my input is 12 , output is  '\x0c\x00' , of length 2 byte as expected, but when i am giving input as 12345 ,  which is < 2 ** 16 - 1(can accommodate in two bytes ) output is '90' which is also of two byte , but i am expecting output as '0x3039' as in the case of 12 as input , Just wanted to know why function is returning different in case of input as 12345

Answer (score 0):

`'90'` is two bytes. The first byte is 0x39 and the second is 0x30.

```
>>> hex(12345)
'0x3039'
```

**TL;DR:** You are getting the correct result.